# change size of array with combobox

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, combobox

I have a two dimensional array of buttons, set to produce a 6x6 grid. I also have a combobox containing the different sizes that I want the array to change to when clicked. How do I go about this?

```
            // Initializing 2D buttons with values i,j
            btn[i][j] = button;
            button.setPrefSize(35, 40);
            gridPane.add(button, i, j);
            button.setDisable(false);
        }
    }

    final ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
    cb.getItems().addAll(
        "4x4",
        "6x6",
        "8x8",
        "10x10" 
    );

    gridPane.add(cb, 11, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all the stuff required to fill the `gridpane` in a method and call it when the `combobox` changes (I created the `init()` just to have a place to put the code).

Add a `listener` on the `ComboBox` and get the text when the value changes, take the 2 `ints` and give them to the method that will refresh

```
final List<String> values = Arrays.asList("", "X", "O");
final GridPane gridPane /* = */:
final ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>();

public void init() {
    addButtonToGrid(6, 6);
    cb.getItems().addAll("4x4", "6x6", "8x8", "10x10");
    cb.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        String[] size = newValue.split("x");
        addButtonToGrid(Integer.parseInt(size[0]),Integer.parseInt(size[1]));
    });
}

private void addButtonToGrid(int sizeR, int sizeC) {
    gridPane.getChildren().clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeC; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeR; j++) {
            final Button button = new Button("");
            button.setOnAction(event -> {
                int valueIndex = values.indexOf(button.getText());
                button.setText(values.get((valueIndex + 1) % values.size()));
            });
            button.setPrefSize(35, 40);
            gridPane.add(button, i, j);
            button.setDisable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ive added the rest of my code, could you show me where this needs to go please?

Comment: @123abc i've edited, if you need to keep all button in a `List` you can also, make it an attribut, clear it in the `addButtonToGrid` and add the button each iteration